# UnknownHostException in android

Tags: android, exception, host

When i run my application for
sometime, suddenly the network is getting disconnected and i am
getting the unknownhostexception in my application. In that case if i
check the browser, the same exception occurs.I don't know why internet
is getting disconnected suddenly. It works fine only if i re start the
emulator again.  If any one knows and provides the solution, it will
be very much helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

See the below link: 
http://hubpages.com/hub/Tips-to-solve-the-UnknownHostException-on-Android

Answer (score 2):

Delete the old emulator and create a new one.
This will help