# Starting the Android emulator without the webcam dialog

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, junit, automated-tests

Every time I launch the Android emulator under Windows, it asks me for which webcam I want to use. Is there a way to get rid of this dialog?

What I need is to start the emulator [*] automatically from a batch file that is supposed to run unsupervised, at night, to perform smoke test on a software. Obviously, the webcam dialog blocks the execution

Disabling the camera support, setting webcam count to zero and running from command line with -webcam off won't help. Also:

```
emulator @Gingerbread -webcam list
```

gives no output.

Any suggestions?

DeK

[*] We actually want to launch the emulator several times, at regular intervals, to avoid this issue:

[UnknownHostException in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310634/unknownhostexception-in-android)

hence we can't just leave the emulator open on the machine where the test is supposed to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create my own AVDs and if the emulated device does not have a camera you will not get the webcam dialogue.

My AVD is called "HTC-Desire.avd" and in its config.ini I have put the line "hw.camera=no"

If you need more information about AVDs you may find this link useful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html